# Different date types manipulation

Tags: asp.net, sql, c, date

I am currently stuck with a database issue where I need to manipulate data using my database inserts. I am currently doing a website with C# ASP.NET on Visual studio 2012 and the database I am using is SQL Management 2008.

Firstly,  I currently store my System.Date into a string  and store it as a nvarchar datatype in my database. If I would like to perhaps get the latest 10 rows from for example, user= 'x', how should I actually go about doing the SELECT statement to only get the data I specified?

And I currently store information like Date Of Birth using the calander Ajax toolkit so the format the dates are saved in is in month/day/year format. The data is stored into my database as a nvarchar as well. If I want to perhaps calculate the age of user='x' how should I calculate it?

Comment: Why are you storing it as an nvarchar to start with? It's logically a date/time, not a string - so *store* it as a date/time. Get rid of the string part, and all your formatting problems go away too.

Comment: After it's a proper Date.  SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Table WHERE User= 'X' ORDER BY Date DESC.   You could also use GETDATE() when records are inserted in your SQL table for timestamps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [Jon's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705575/different-date-types-manipulation#comment24047448_16705575) about storing the data properly as a datetime is spot on:

> Why are you storing it as an nvarchar to start with? It's logically a
>   date/time, not a string - so store it as a date/time. Get rid of the
>   string part, and all your formatting problems go away too.

Definitely do that if you can.

If, for some reason, you can't change your database structure, you can use a `CAST` / `CONVERT` statement in your `ORDER BY` clause to get what you want:

```
SELECT TOP 10 *, CAST(yourDateField AS datetime) AS convertedDate
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    user='Some user'
ORDER BY CAST(yourDateField AS datetime) DESC
```

This assumes that your nvarchar data can be properly converted to a datetime (which it should be if you're using the Ajax Control Toolkit calendar extender).